# Cannot view "Delete this answered question?" dialog on small screens

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

#### I thought about deleting a question recently, so I clicked the delete link.

> [image: delete link]

The **Delete this answered question?** dialog appeared, but it was **not entirely visible on my small iPhone SE**. Worse, I couldn't even scroll to read the entire dialog!

> [image: Delete this answered question? dialog]

I was able to reproduce the results using Chrome on my laptop and decreasing the width of the page.

> [image: Delete this answered question? dialog]

Comment: I see that the other linked dup was a dup to this question, not the other way around. But I see that the bug was fixed. Hooray for accessibility :-)